# Xamarin override swipe back in IOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am building an app using Xamarin.Forms (5.0.0.2291) with shell navigation. On each page I added a 'GoBack' command linked to the Shell.BackButtonBehavior. However in IOS when the user swipes left he goes back to the previous page without passing this command.
Is there a way to override the default swipe left and re-route it to my 'GoBack' function?
PS: I know how to disable the swipe left.

Regards,
Andy

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem as well. The best way that I found was to override the `OnDisappearing()` method on the page in the Xamarin Forms layer. `OnDisappearing` is called when the user presses the back button or swipes to go back on both iOS and Android. Below I have added a sample page that shows what this would look like.

SamplePage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="Sample.SamplePage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Label
            Text="Hello world!"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

SamplePage.xaml.cs

```
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace Sample
{
  [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
  public partial class SamplePage
  {
    public SamplePage()
    {
      this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
      this.CustomLogic();
      base.OnDisappearing();
    }

    private void CustomLogic()
    {
      // perform custom logic here
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please try custom renderer

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Appname.Views.DeviceInfoPage), typeof(Appname.iOS.Renderers.NoSwipeBackPageRenderer))]
namespace Appname.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class NoSwipeBackPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewDidAppear(animated);
            var navctrl = this.ViewController.NavigationController;
            navctrl.InteractivePopGestureRecognizer.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This disables the swipe back, which I already implemented. However I'm looking for a way to override it, so capture the swipe back and execute my own code